# Variables vacías cuando las utilizo dentro de un Switch en C

Tags: c

El programa me pone a cero / vacías las variables declaradas fuera del switch cuando las intento utilizar dentro del switch. (Por ejemplo cantidadPrimos, la cual siempre, independientemente de si introduzco su valor por teclado o la inicializo a cualquier número, se pone a cero )

No logro visualizar dónde estoy comentiendo el fallo y estoy bastante seguro de que debe de ser un muy tonto, pero me encuentro frustrado, desesperado y desde luego fuera de tiempo.

De resto todo compila y accede a las funciones, no me salta ningun tipo de error.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
    int main()
    {

        printf("Bienvenido al programa\n");

        printf ("\n\t¿Cuantos números quiere generar?\n");

        int cantidadPrimos;

        scanf ("%d",&cantidadPrimos);

        int* numerosPrimos = (int*) calloc (cantidadPrimos, sizeof(int));
        numerosPrimos = generarNumerosPrimos (cantidadPrimos);

            char eleccion;
            char nombreFichero[200];


              printf ("\n\t¿Deseas imprimir los números o almacenarlos en un fichero ? [ I / F ]\n");
              printf ("\t Si desea salir tan solo introduzca [ E ]\n");


            scanf("%s",&eleccion);

            switch (eleccion)
            {

            case 'I':

                imprimirPrimos (numerosPrimos, cantidadPrimos);

                break;

            case 'F':

                printf("Introduzca el nombre del fichero: \n");
                scanf("%s",nombreFichero);

                strcat (nombreFichero, ".txt");

                FILE *punteroFile = fopen(nombreFichero,"rb+");

                if (punteroFile == NULL){ // El fichero no existe, hay que crearlo.

                  punteroFile = fopen(nombreFichero, "wb");

                  if (punteroFile == NULL){
                      printf("Dicho archivo ya existe\n");
                      fclose (punteroFile);

                    }else{

                      for (int iterador = 0; iterador < cantidadPrimos; iterador++){
                          fprintf(punteroFile, "%d ", numerosPrimos[iterador]);
                      }

                      fclose (punteroFile);

                    }

                }else if ('0'){
                      printf("\nHa habido un error al intentar abrir el fichero\n");
                      fclose (punteroFile);
                      printf ("¿Quizás exista un archivo con el mismo nombre?\n");
                    }


            break;

            default:
                printf("Opción no válida, introduzca I (Imprimir) | F (Fichero) | E (Exit) ");
                break;

              }

                      printf ("Gracias por usar el programa\n");
          }


 bool esPrimo (int numero)
    {
      int divisores = 0;

      //printf ("El numero es: %d \n", numero);

        for (int iterador = 1; iterador <= numero; iterador++){
            if (numero % iterador == 0)
                divisores++;
        }

      //printf ("Tiene %d divisores\n", divisores);

        if (divisores <= 2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    int cantidadDePrimos (int* numeros, int cantidadNumeros)
    {

      int cantidadPrimos = 0;

      for (int iterador = 0; iterador < cantidadNumeros; iterador++)
      {
        if (esPrimo(numeros[iterador]))
            cantidadPrimos++;
      }

          return cantidadPrimos;
    }



    int* depurarNumerosPrimos (int* numeros, int cantidadNumeros)
    {

        int* numerosPrimos;
        int cantidadPrimos = cantidadDePrimos (numeros,cantidadNumeros);

        numerosPrimos = (int*) calloc (cantidadPrimos, sizeof(int));


        int indicePrimos = 0;
        for (int iterador = 0; iterador < cantidadNumeros; iterador++){
          if (esPrimo(numeros[iterador])){
              numerosPrimos[indicePrimos] = numeros[iterador];
              indicePrimos++;
          }
        }

        return numerosPrimos;

    }

    void imprimirPrimos (int* numerosPrimos, int cantidadPrimos){

      printf ("\n\t¿En cuantas columnas desea imprimir los números?\n");
      int numeroColumnas = 0, contadorColumnas = 0;
      scanf ("%d",&numeroColumnas);

        printf("\nLos números primos encontrados son: \n\n");
        printf ("\t");

         for (int iterador = 0; iterador < cantidadPrimos; iterador++){
              if (contadorColumnas == numeroColumnas){
                  contadorColumnas = 0;
                  printf("\n\t");
              }else contadorColumnas++;
              printf("%d ", numerosPrimos[iterador]);
            }

          printf("\n");
    }

    int* generarNumerosPrimos (int cantidadPrimos)
    {

      int* numerosPrimos = (int*) calloc (cantidadPrimos, sizeof(int));

      int contadorPrimos = 0;
      int numerosNaturales = 2;

      while (contadorPrimos != cantidadPrimos){

          if (esPrimo(numerosNaturales)){
              numerosPrimos[contadorPrimos] = numerosNaturales;
              contadorPrimos++;
            }

            numerosNaturales++;
          }

          return numerosPrimos;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a cambiar `scanf("%s",&eleccion);` por `scanf("%c",&eleccion);`

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta puede ser de ayuda y resolver el problema, sería ideal que añadieras una pequeña descripción de por qué o cómo funciona. Te recomiendo que leas [answer], donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar y completar tus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que limpiar la basura con la función `fflush (stdin);` para evitar saltos o residuos en el programa. Las cadenas se leen sin ampersand pues son arreglos, pero te conviene leer un carácter porque un switch solo acepta datos de un dígito y una cadena tiene más de un digito. Por último veo que faltan las librerías y los prototipos de las funciones.
Programa completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

void imprimirPrimos (int* numerosPrimos, int cantidadPrimos);
int* generarNumerosPrimos (int cantidadPrimos);

int main()
{

    printf("Bienvenido al programa\n");

    printf ("\n\t¿Cuantos números quiere generar?\n");

    int cantidadPrimos, iterador;

    scanf ("%d",&cantidadPrimos);

    int* numerosPrimos = (int*) calloc (cantidadPrimos, sizeof(int));
    numerosPrimos = generarNumerosPrimos (cantidadPrimos);

    char eleccion;
    char nombreFichero[200];
    fflush(stdin);

    printf ("\n\t¿Deseas imprimir los números o almacenarlos en un fichero ? [ I / F ]\n");
    printf ("\t Si desea salir tan solo introduzca [ E ]\n");


    scanf("%c",&eleccion);

    switch (eleccion)
    {

    case 'I':

        imprimirPrimos (numerosPrimos, cantidadPrimos);

        break;

    case 'F':

        printf("Introduzca el nombre del fichero: \n");
        scanf("%s",nombreFichero);

        strcat (nombreFichero, ".txt");

        FILE *punteroFile = fopen(nombreFichero,"rb+");

        if (punteroFile == NULL){ // El fichero no existe, hay que crearlo.

            punteroFile = fopen(nombreFichero, "wb");

            if (punteroFile == NULL){
                printf("Dicho archivo ya existe\n");
                fclose (punteroFile);

            }else{

                for (iterador = 0; iterador < cantidadPrimos; iterador++){
                    fprintf(punteroFile, "%d ", numerosPrimos[iterador]);
                }

                fclose (punteroFile);

            }

        }else if ('0'){
            printf("\nHa habido un error al intentar abrir el fichero\n");
            fclose (punteroFile);
            printf ("¿Quizás exista un archivo con el mismo nombre?\n");
        }


        break;

    default:
        printf("Opción no válida, introduzca I (Imprimir) | F (Fichero) | E (Exit) ");
        break;

    }
    printf ("Gracias por usar el programa\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}


bool esPrimo (int numero)
{
    int divisores = 0, iterador;

    //printf ("El numero es: %d \n", numero);

    for (iterador = 1; iterador <= numero; iterador++){
        if (numero % iterador == 0)
            divisores++;
    }

    //printf ("Tiene %d divisores\n", divisores);

    if (divisores <= 2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


int cantidadDePrimos (int* numeros, int cantidadNumeros)
{

    int cantidadPrimos = 0, iterador;

    for (iterador = 0; iterador < cantidadNumeros; iterador++)
    {
        if (esPrimo(numeros[iterador]))
            cantidadPrimos++;
    }

    return cantidadPrimos;
}



int* depurarNumerosPrimos (int* numeros, int cantidadNumeros)
{

    int* numerosPrimos;
    int cantidadPrimos = cantidadDePrimos (numeros,cantidadNumeros);

    numerosPrimos = (int*) calloc (cantidadPrimos, sizeof(int));


    int indicePrimos = 0, iterador;
    for (iterador = 0; iterador < cantidadNumeros; iterador++){
        if (esPrimo(numeros[iterador])){
            numerosPrimos[indicePrimos] = numeros[iterador];
            indicePrimos++;
        }
    }

    return numerosPrimos;

}

void imprimirPrimos (int* numerosPrimos, int cantidadPrimos){

    printf ("\n\t¿En cuantas columnas desea imprimir los números?\n");
    int numeroColumnas = 0, contadorColumnas = 0;
    int iterador;
    scanf ("%d",&numeroColumnas);

    printf("\nLos números primos encontrados son: \n\n");
    printf ("\t");

    for (iterador = 0; iterador < cantidadPrimos; iterador++){
        if (contadorColumnas == numeroColumnas){
            contadorColumnas = 0;
            printf("\n\t");
        }else contadorColumnas++;
        printf("%d ", numerosPrimos[iterador]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int* generarNumerosPrimos (int cantidadPrimos)
{

    int* numerosPrimos = (int*) calloc (cantidadPrimos, sizeof(int));

    int contadorPrimos = 0;
    int numerosNaturales = 2;

    while (contadorPrimos != cantidadPrimos){

        if (esPrimo(numerosNaturales)){
            numerosPrimos[contadorPrimos] = numerosNaturales;
            contadorPrimos++;
        }

        numerosNaturales++;
    }

    return numerosPrimos;

}
```